# Get element of three list combine one by one

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following:

```
Composition1SB = {100, 70, 21, 55, 12, 85, 0};
EaRSBdata = {87.59500266062417`, 79.21523941596703`, 
   72.12306732186894`, 56.693107910697165`, 56.89958615877694`, 
   135.91522196805766`, 69.27255661695618`};
ErrorEaRSBdata = {4.823279954454718`, 4.690600564437454`, 
   3.9811685696852495`, 1.8794098881159669`, 2.7677528848843247`, 
   21.978521496856732`, 4.281624335790518`};
```

and I want to get a list that combines all the first elements of the lists, all the seconds and so on. Something like this `{{100,87.59500266062417,4.823279954454718},{70,79.21523941596703,4.690600564437454}.....etc}`

I am trying something like this but it does not work:

`newlist = Partition[Riffle[Composition1SB, EaRSBdata, ErrorEaRSBdata],  3]`

I can do it for instance for two list (but not for three) such as:

`newlist=Partition[Riffle[Composition1SB, EaRSBdata], 2]`

How can I do this for three lists?

Comment: You might be looking for `Transpose`. `Transpose[{Composition1SB, EaRSBdata, ErrorEaRSBdata}]`.

Comment: Thank you! that was it !

Comment: @John:  Let me recommend you simplify your questions as they will be clearer to you (so you might solve them on your own) and to potential solvers.  Why not:  `data1 = {87, 79, 72, 56, 57, 135, 69 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Transpose[{Composition1SB, EaRSBdata, ErrorEaRSBdata}]

(*  {{100, 87.595, 4.82328}, {70, 79.2152, 4.6906}, {21, 72.1231, 
  3.98117}, {55, 56.6931, 1.87941}, {12, 56.8996, 2.76775}, {85, 
  135.915, 21.9785}, {0, 69.2726, 4.28162}}  *)
```

Have fun!